# How to clean node_modules folder when prepping for deployment

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, resource-cleanup

How would I go about cleaning the **node_modules** folder when prepping my code for deployment.

I am making an app using **node-webkit** and would prefer to include the least amount of files possible when bundling the final version of the app as the unzip process takes some time.

I've looked at `npm dedupe` and use `npm install --production` to get rid of duplicates and fetch only production files, however I am still left with `Readme` files, `benchmarks`, `tests` and `build` files which I don't need.

What I would like to end up with for each module in the `node_modules` folder is a `LICENSE` file if it exists, the `package.json` and anything else that I need for the module to run, but nothing more.

The question: [How to automatically clean a node_modules directory for a SCM commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477698/how-to-automatically-clean-a-node-modules-directory-for-a-scm-commit) was heading somewhat in the same direction, but it is talking about committing so not really what I am looking for.

The question: [NPM clean modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351784/npm-clean-modules) again was somewhat along the same lines as mine, but not quite fully there.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18472948/771466) answer helps as it is more efficient version for `dedupe` for bundling the final app.

**Update**
I tried the custom module linked from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17239083/compacting-node-modules-for-client-side-deployment?rq=1) but it didn't seem to work correctly, even after some fiddling about.

With all that said, I haven't quite found the right answer yet.

---

Here's an example of what I am looking for.

In my project I currently have two dependencies: `socket.io` and `socket.io-client`.

Together they make up **15 MB** with **550** files in **110** folders.

Manually cleaning `readme`, `makefile`, `VC++` build files such as `.pdb` and `.obj` and other unnecessary files I was able to shrink it down to **2.74 MB** with **265** files in **73** folders.
This is with just two modules.

I would like to find out if there is a way to do this automatically, preferably with `npm`.

Comment: you could write `.bat | .sh` scripts to automate your release.etc.. but soon you will just end up using `grunt`

Comment: I'm open to creating a grunt task, but I wonder if there's a proper way of doing this...

Comment: You could make your own dependency checker, if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Check out the [modclean](https://www.npmjs.com/package/modclean) npm package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well cleaning the `node_modules` for the deployment for a webkit application, its kind of difficult, because of the modules inside `node_modules` directory are installed with or without test files other misc files and so, if the owner of the module, has declared an `.npmignore` file with dir/files such as `tests` or `examples` those will be excluded from packaging process when the owner publishes his module, but it will exist in the repository (git) as normal.

[Exclude test code in npm package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617753/exclude-test-code-in-npm-package)

the above is left in module owners hands, if he/she "forgets" to make one, then package will contain pretty much everything.

---

Note that since you don't use the `development` package of `socket.io` or `socket.io-client` it doesn't mean you have to `npm install socket.io --save-dev`, a simple `npm install socket.io -V` would install the production package as it was uploaded by its owner.

---

A possible workaround would be to make a `grunt` task, to clean your entire `node_modules` as you would like it to be.

a couple of rules would be

- `test` or `tests` directory or `*test*.js` files
- `build` directories (not sure about it might contain some binaries sometimes that are necessary)
- `history.md`

[GruntJS](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started)

---

Hope i helped somehow, also take a look at [Tilemill](https://github.com/mapbox/tilemill) and how they deploy their application.

Answer (score 9):

This module attempts to intelligently cleanup the node_modules folder:

[modclean](https://github.com/KyleRoss/modclean)

Install:

```
npm install modclean -g
```

or

```
npm install modclean --save-dev
```

Usage:

```
modclean
```

It uses a set of default patterns to remove unnecessary bloat from modules throughout the dependency tree.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are interested in this little `find` command, which I've assembled over time. Please be aware, that this is not a "one-size-fits-all" solution! You need to check it very carefully against your requirements. It is intended for node.js environments and will definitely destroy browser environments. I run in a bash script as a `postinstall` script in npm.

**DO NOT BLINDLY COPY 'N PASTE**. You have been warned!

```
find node_modules \( \( -name "dist" -or -name "ts" -or -name "logos" -or -name "min" -or -name "test*" -or -name "doc*" -or -name "tst" -or -name "example*" -or -name "build" -or -name "man" -or -name "benchmark*" \) -and -type d \) -or \
   \( \( -iname "readme*" -or -iname "changelog*" -or -iname "notice*" -or -iname "test*.js" -or -iname "*.min.js" \) -and -type f \) -or \
   \( -path "*moment-timezone/data/unpacked*" -and -type d \)
```

To be sure, I've not added the final line `| xargs rm -rf`. You can safely execute the above command without deleting anything and later add the pipe to `xargs` with `rm` to make it really happen.

What does the find command do? I'll explain it pattern by pattern.

1. `\( \( -name "dist" -or -name "ts" -or -name "logos" -or -name "min" -or -name "test*" -or -name "doc*" -or -name "tst" -or -name "example*" -or -name "build" -or -name "man" -or -name "benchmark*" \) -and -type d \)` => search for directories that match on the text in the quotes. The `*` is a wildcard.
2. `\( \( -iname "readme*" -or -iname "changelog*" -or -iname "notice*" -or -iname "test*.js" -or -iname "*.min.js" \) -and -type f \)` => search for files in any folder where the text in the quotes matches regardless of the case. **Especially the pattern `"*.min.js"` could be dangerous for some people.**
3. `\( -path "*moment-timezone/data/unpacked*" -and -type d \)` => remove the unpacked data from moment. This also saves plenty of space.

Feel free to improve this!

Answer (score 2):

Modules installed with NPM should never contain development files (i.e. benchmarks, tests etc.). If they are included you should contact the module maintainer and ask to have them added to `.npmignore`.

*Note: Development files in this case means the files that are needed for development of the actual module and not your application.*

It's been suggested before, but having a `deploy` task in `grunt` is probably a good idea. Just make sure to `test` the application after the cleanup. [`grunt-contrib-clean`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean) is great for cleaning.

See [`.npmignore`](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/.npmignore) from `connect` for some ideas on which files/directories that shouldn't be in a production package.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into this for deploying to AWS's elasticbeanstalk. When I run the `eb deploy` command it was magically finding what files to upload and it wasn't getting any of the `bower_components` or `node_modules`. I wondered how.

It turns out that `eb deploy` invokes `git archive` under the hood. `git archive` checks out the branch you specify and makes a zip of all the files.

Presumably you don't commit things like your node_modules or bower_components directories to git, so `git archive` might be a solution to your problem. If you want to avoid things like test cases and README files and so on, you might still need to do some tagging in git. But you're starting at a substantially smaller list and you're obviously excluding the bulk of the stuff you want to exclude.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `npm prune`

> npm prune `[<name> [<name ...]]`
>
> This command removes "extraneous" packages. If a package name is
>   provided, then only packages matching one of the supplied names are
>   removed.
>
> Extraneous packages are packages that are not listed on the parent
>   package's dependencies list.

Documentation https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prune

Comment: `npm prune` only removes packages in node_modules that are not present in package.json, it doesn't "clean" them

Comment: Using the --production flag will remove the devDependencies from node_modules, which is what OP is looking for.