# Prepare node_modules for distribution?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, node-webkit

Are there ways to make node_modules more compact for client side usage? For example with nodewebkit?

I think about removing unecessary files and minification.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clean node\_modules folder when prepping for deployment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723657/how-to-clean-node-modules-folder-when-prepping-for-deployment)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `npm install --production`, so you don't install unnecessary modules for your production environment like eg: grunt, gulp, mocha, etc. Of course it depends if you install the development modules with `npm install --save-dev`

Comment: Thanks...I already go this way! I just wanna automatically remove unnecessary file out of my module folders and maybe zip them or something else

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are ways.

Do the following in this order:

- `npm install --production`
- `npm dedupe` to flatten the hirarchy and remove duplicates
- use [grunt package minifier](https://github.com/salsita/grunt-package-minifier) if you have a builder it will remove all the unneccesery files (Readme's, make files, tests, documentation etc.)